# Caching Data on Form Load

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a c# windows form that pulls a generic list on load using a thread worker. This populates a drop down of client numbers.

```
private void ZurichAccountTrades_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   tbLocation.Text = @"C:\Reports\Output\";
   lbGettingData.Visible = true;
   CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
   var thdWorker = new Thread(PopulateDropDownPersonNumbers);
   thdWorker.Start();
}

private void PopulateDropDownPersonNumbers()
{
        ddProviderNo.Enabled = false;

  progressBar1.Increment(10);

  //Get data somehow here....

  foreach (var person in providerPNos)
  {
    ddProviderNo.Items.Add(person.PersonNo);
    progressBar1.Increment(1);
  }
  progressBar1.Increment(100);
  lbGettingData.Visible = false;
  ddProviderNo.Enabled = true;
  progressBar1.Value = 0;
}

private void ddProviderNo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 //What do I do here??
}
```

What I want is when a user selects a client number the client name (which is held in the same list) is displayed automatically.

How can this be done?

Comment: You want Name to display instead of No?

Comment: What type/class is `providerPNos` and how would you access the client name?

Comment: Hi, providerPNos is a generic list.

Comment: client name (which is held in the same list) is displayed automatically on where?

Comment: so I want the user to select a client (here called person) from a dropdown, and the name of that client displayed in a text box underneath their selection automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add object `Person` instead of `PersonNo`

```
  ddProviderNo.Items.Add(person);
```

Then:

```
private void ddProviderNo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
    textBox.Text = (comboBox.SelectedItem as Person).Name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can bind client name to DisplayName Property Of ComboBox. then when it changed, you can use it..